# strange character encoding of stored data , old script is showing them fine new one doesn't

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, character-encoding

I'm trying to rewrite an old website .
it's in persian which uses perso/arabic characters .

```sql
CREATE DATABASE `db` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci;
USE `db`;
```

Almost all my table/columns COLLATE are set to `utf8_persian_ci`

I'm using codeigniter for my new script and i have

```
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_persian_ci',
```

In the database settings  , so there is no  problem there .

So here is the strange part

The old script is using some sort of database engine called `TUBADBENGINE` or `TUBA DB ENGINE` ... nothing special .

When i enter some data in the database (in persian) using the old script , when i look into database , characters are stored like `Ø¹Ù…Ø±Ø§Ù†`  .

The old script fetch/shows that data fine , but the new script shows them with the same weird font/charset as database

So when i enter `اااا` ,  database stored data looks like `Ø¹Ù…Ø±Ø§Ù` , when i fetch it in the new script i see  `Ø¹Ù…Ø±Ø§Ù` but in  the old script i see `اااا`

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tnewsgroups` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fName` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tnewsgroups`
--

INSERT INTO `tnewsgroups` (`ID`, `fName`) VALUES
(1, 'Ø¹Ù…Ø±Ø§Ù†'),
(2, 'Ù…Ø¹Ù…Ø§Ø±ÛŒ'),
(3, 'Ø¨Ø±Ù‚'),
(4, 'Ù…Ú©Ø§Ù†ÛŒÚ©'),
(5, 'test'),
(6, 'test2');
```

---

In the other hand when i enter `ااااا` directly in the database

Of course i have the same `اااا` stored in the database

The new script is showing it fine

But in the old script i get `????`

Can anyone make any sense of this ?

Here is the tuba engin

https://github.com/maxxxir/mz-codeigniter-crud/blob/master/tuba.php

Usage example from old script :

```
define("database_type" , "MYSQL");
define("database_ip" , "localhost");
define("database_un" , "root");
define("database_pw" , "");
define("database_name" , "nezam2");
define("database_connectionstring" , "");
$db = new TUBADBENGINE(database_type , database_ip , database_un , database_pw , database_name , database_connectionstring);
$db->Select("SELECT * FROM tnews limit 3");
if ($db->Lasterror() != "") { echo "<B><Font color=red>ÎØÇ ! áØÝÇ ãÌÏøÏÇ ÊáÇÔ ˜äíÏ";  exit(); }
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $db->Count() ; $i++) {
    $row = $db->Next();
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In short, because this has been discussed a thousand times before:

1. PHP holds a string, say `"漢字"`, encoded in UTF-8. The bytes for this are `E6 BC A2 E5 AD 97`.
2. It sends this string over a **database connection which is set to `latin1`**.
3. The database receives the bytes `E6 BC A2 E5 AD 97`, thinking those represent `latin1` characters.
4. The database stores the characters `æ¼¢å­` (the characters that `E6 BC A2 E5 AD 97` maps to in `latin1`).
5. The same process reversed makes PHP receive the same bytes, which it then treats as UTF-8. The roundtrip works fine for PHP, even though the database doesn't treat the characters as it should.

So the problem here was that the database connection was set incorrectly when the data was entered into the database. You'll have to convert the data in the database to the correct characters. Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(field_name USING latin1) USING utf8) FROM table_name
```

Maybe `utf8` isn't what you need here, experiment. If that works, change this into an `UPDATE` statement to update the data permanently.

Comment: @Deceze: Is there any easy way to perform such conversion for each field in database?

Comment: @Abdel5 Dumping the database and reimporting it with the correct/wrong combination of import/export charset is probably the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

The [deceze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20237671/2342558) is excellent but I can add some info that may help to handle lots of records without test them manually.

If the conversion `CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(field_name USING latin1) USING utf8)` fails, it print `NULL` instead of the `field_name` content.

So I use this one to find those record:

```
SELECT IFNULL(
    CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(field_name USING latin1) USING utf8)
    , '**************************************************')
FROM table_name
```

or this one:

```
SELECT id, field_name, CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(field_name USING latin1) USING utf8)
FROM table_name
WHERE CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(field_name USING latin1) USING utf8) IS NULL
```

And the `UPDATE` with the clause to affect only records on which the conversion success:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET
field_name = CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(field_name USING latin1) USING utf8mb4 )
WHERE
CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(field_name USING latin1) USING utf8mb4) IS NOT NULL
```