# Restored Database with Latin1 connection, when my data is UTF-8 encoded

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I recently had to move my website's database to a new host, because my old host couldn't handle the influx of traffic I was receiving.

I used the shell command prompt to restore my database from an sql dump file.  Sadly I hadn't realised at the time that the default connection was latin1.

I now have a situation where my older data is stored in the database using a latin1 connection, but the data is UTF-8 encoded.  I think that means it's double encoded?

I know that I can connect to the database now with a latin1 connection using PHP and the UTF-8 data displays OK again.  However, I need to perform a mass update on all of the affected columns on the database.

Is there a way, without using a PHP script that I can update the data in the columns?

Comment: possible duplicate of [strange character encoding of stored data , old script is showing them fine new one doesn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237474/strange-character-encoding-of-stored-data-old-script-is-showing-them-fine-new)

Comment: Perfect, the script on that page did the trick perfectly.  I have updated all of the text fields in my database... I take it that I don't have to update any number (int) fields?

Comment: No, numbers are numbers. Only text/varchar/char fields are affected by encodings.