# Edit tables from phpmyadmin (encoding issue)

Tags: character-encoding, phpmyadmin

I want to manually update a table created by CakePHP using phpMyAdmin interface, but I cannot put characters like `é` or `ç`because the fields actually looks like this.

[image]

Current table interclassement: `utf8_unicode_ci`

Is there any way to display these characters correctly in phpMyAdmin (knowing that they are well displayed in my website ) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [strange character encoding of stored data , old script is showing them fine new one doesn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237474/strange-character-encoding-of-stored-data-old-script-is-showing-them-fine-new), [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: characters are displayed correctly in my website, just want to edit them from phpmyadmin

Comment: Yes, the problem is that you haven't set the `encoding` parameter in Cake's database configuration to `utf8`. So the connection encoding is wrong and your data is stored as garbage. You're not the first to experience this and it's all explained in the above links.

Comment: there is no way to edit them so ?

Comment: Only if you misencode the content the same way it's misencoded now.