# Mysql vs Mysqli with currency symbols

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, symbols

I had all db connection with "old" mysql connection.. Now I changed to mysqli. 
Before all changes £ symbol was displayed from db properly now after I changed to mysqli connection it shows only a question mark. I changed collation for that column where £ symbol is - no changes. Any advices?

Comment: Have you tried setting the character set to UTF-8 with mysqli_set_charset()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237474/strange-character-encoding-of-stored-data-old-script-is-showing-them-fine-new

Comment: I set utf-8 in phpmyadmin I might try your suggestion

Comment: @MattThompson nope,doesnt work

Comment: There are multiple places where you have to set utf-8. And then there are multiple was of having your content in the wrong charset altogether. If your characters come out wrong, You HAVE wrong encoding in one of the many parts of your pipeline. Sad, but true.

Comment: BTW, are you even sure your data is actually utf-8? Maybe it's something bad like Latin-1 or swedish.

Comment: Well I did set to utf-8 with meta tags, I am not an expert for these things, I know that you can set a different charset in phpadmin.. How you can test ot out are you using utf-8 in your entire website?