# MySQL migration issues with UTF8

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

We are currently migrating a legacy application from an old server to a new server. We're running into an issue where utf-8 encoded data was stored in a latin1 table.

On our old server, we had PHP 5.2 running, and this outputted the data as "Donâ€™t", but the browser interpreted the data as "Don't" (we have content-type tag set to UTF-8).
However, on our new server with PHP 5.4, it utf-8 encodes before outputted to the browser, causing the browser to interpret it as "Donâ€™t".

Is there a way of correcting the data in the tables?
If it helps, we still have access to our old server.

Comment: 1. Update your database to contain actual UTF-8 data according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237474/strange-character-encoding-of-stored-data-old-script-is-showing-them-fine-new, 2. use [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through), 3. [don't `utf8_encode`](http://kunststube.net/encoding)

Comment: @deceze Thank you, the first question you linked had an answer that fixed our problem.