# Encoding error with polish charset during transfer of database / server seting up

Tags: mysql, wordpress, character-encoding, phpmyadmin, mojibake

I am trying to transfer one of my databases from one host (home.pl) to another (my newly set server). The script that I am trying to transfer is wordpress. Unluckily irrespective of the method used I am struggling with encoding problems.

**New host configuration**

In my new server I am using the following directives in my.cnf:

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
character-set-server = utf8
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_general_ci' 
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8' 

[client]
default-character-set=utf8
```

My mySQL vars:

```
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  utf8
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    utf8
character_set_system    utf8
collation_connection    utf8_general_ci
collation_database  utf8_general_ci
collation_server    utf8_general_ci
```

Php.ini on new server:

```
; PHP's default character set is set to UTF-8.
; http://php.net/default-charset
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

**Old host configuration**

I have runned SHOW VARIABLES in my old host from which I am trying to transfer database and I got the following:

```
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_database  utf8
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    latin2
character_set_system    utf8
/usr/local/pssql55/share/charsets/
collation_connection    utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_database  utf8_polish_ci
collation_server    latin2_general_ci
```

**Transfer methods tried out**

1) Transfer via phpmyadmin

I have tried using PHPMYADMIN export/import. In particular I have pointed out UTF-8 as file character set both during export and import via phpmyadmin.

What is strange both in phpmyadmin on source server and new host I don't see polish chars (the output is the same without polish chars).

2) Export / Import via mysql dump

I have tried also to use:

```
 mysqldump -h OLD_HOST -u OLD_USER -p DB | mysql -h localhost -u root NEW DATABASE
```

but the encoding also fails.

Tried to use also encoding variables but it also failed:

```
 mysqldump --default-character-set=latin1  | mysql --default-character-set=utf8
```

**Dump file**

In my dump file using Programers Notepad with UTF-8 encoding set,  charcters look like this:

```
"Ä" instead of "ę"
```

Opening them in microsoft word I see

```
Ä™ instead of "ę"
```

The encoding converter (gżegżółka) recognises that the file is in:
C:\Users\mkondej001\Desktop\14271425_mk.sql

```
Kodowanie: Unicode UTF-8
EOL: LF (Unix)
```

**Any clues how to transfer DB / set server variables correctly ?**

Comment: I don't think this is a server issue at all. Does PhpMyAdmin ask what encoding to use when exporting and when importing? Have you inspected the dump in a regular text editor where you can select the encoding?

Comment: Álvaro G. Vicario please find above updated background, relating to your questions.

Comment: The **ę** character properly encoded as UTF-8 displays as **Ä™** when you open it with a tool that doesn't understand UTF-8, which is curiously similar to the **Ä** you are getting. Are you fully sure that your editor and your application are properly configured to use UTF-8?

Comment: I am getting exactly Ä™ opening the dump file in microsoft word so probably this is editor error. The application that I am trying to transfer is simple wordpress.

Comment: Are you 10000% sure that you have expressly specified UTF-8 when *importing* the file into the target database?

Comment: Pekka 웃: In phpmyadmin I am choosing file encoding as UTF-8. There is no other option avaliable. How should I choose it using mysqldump ?

Comment: Using mysql I have inputed: --default-character-set=utf8.

Comment: You can use --hex-blob when exporting your database, this will prevent encoding issues related to text editor or user environment in general.

Comment: grenoult: mysqldump --hex-blob did not change anything, the result is still the same.

Comment: I have found out that my source datbase was corrupted during process. I loaded backup, cheked that its encoding is ok and now trying the above again.

Comment: --hex-blob does not help with updated database too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I have founded out that the problem was related to the fact that the data was written to SQL incorrectly in my original server.

I ended up with transferring DB using:

```
mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8 [ORYGINAL_DB] | mysql [TARGET_DB] --default-character-set=utf8
```

and the executing:

```
UPDATE [table name] SET [field] = CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT([field] USING latin2) USING utf8)
```

as it was advices here:

[strange character encoding of stored data , old script is showing them fine new one doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237474/strange-character-encoding-of-stored-data-old-script-is-showing-them-fine-new)

Hope that the above solution will be helpful for others too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

(The default is latin11, which leads to `Ä™`.)

Note: `init_connect` is not executed for `root` (or any `SUPER`) user.  So this failed you:

```
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
```

Comment: Based on your sugestion I have tried to dump database to file using mysqldump command, and then using mysql I manually executed "SET NAMES utf8 and then \. dumpfile.sql but it did not helped. I have also tried to comment out  init_connect, then use mysqldump command and mysql with "SET NAMES utf8" and then \. dumpfile.sql but also failed. Would you be so kind and advice on how to perform the transfer properly ?

Comment: I have found out that my source datbase was corrupted during process. I loaded backup, cheked that its encoding is ok and now trying the above again.

Comment: Search for "Mojibake" in this [mysql] forum; I have discussed the details in various ways before.  Maybe something else will help.

Comment: When using mysqldump, be sure to include `--default-character-set=utf8` (or something like that).

Comment: Have been trying various ways but it did not helped. The strange things is that the website on source server (wordpress) shows encoding correctly  but the phpmyadmin on source server not (Ĺ instead of Ł).

Comment: Strange.  I can't think of a way to confuse Ĺ and Ł in any character set.  Do you have another example?