# Determining encoding of mySQL database - website shows chars correctly but phpmyadmin/dump files not

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, mojibake

I am trying to determine encoding of my mySQL database to solve up the mojibake error during database transfer (problem described here: [Encoding error with polish charset during transfer of database / server seting up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424198/encoding-error-with-polish-charset-during-transfer-of-database-server-seting-u)).

To make successful DB transfer I need firstly to  **determine what is original database encoding**. Unluckily I am not sure whether it is indeed UTF-8 as I could expect from mySQL configuration.

```
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_database  utf8
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    latin2
character_set_system    utf8
/usr/local/pssql55/share/charsets/
collation_connection    utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_database  utf8_polish_ci
collation_server    latin2_general_ci
```

In the file exported by phpmyadmin (using default settings) the chars in notepad++ using UTF-8 encoding setting looks like this:

[image: Encoding Phpmyadmin]

Using different styles in Notepad++ does not help and I always see strange characters.

In phpmyadmin I see polish chars like this:
[image]

while on normal webpage on source server with `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` everything looks correctly.

**I am trying to solve what is my database encoding? Is this UTF-8? If yes, then why no editor can read the dumped data?**

Comment: Pretty sure the duplicate applies. If not, tell us why not.

Comment: deceze: Thanks for the link. You are correct the problem is the same though I had to use: CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(... USING latin2) USING utf8).

Comment: Your table/column needs to be `CHARACTER SET utf8`.