# How to convert a string into a readable view

Tags: php, pdo, encoding, character-encoding

From some database i get string, it looks like this

```
[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [body] =>  ÉÓËÒÅÎÎÅ ÔÅÂÅ ÖÅÌÁÀ ã×ÅÔÏ×, ÌÀÂ×É É ËÒÁÓÏÔÙ!
    )
```

How to convert this string into a readable view using php?
I'm use PDO type connection with option "SET NAMES utf8", maybe I need to change this option?

---

Using phpmyadmin i see this table decription

[table description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aunin.png)

and browse

[table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFaRY.png)

Comment: Would be nice to get some more info. What is the original string, or the string you are looking for? What is the original encoding? Etc.

Comment: I add information in question body

Comment: Could be your table / column setting isn't UTF-8.

Comment: Column setting isn't UTF-8, but it demands for other process

Comment: See here for a likely explanation of what's happening: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20237671/476; as for the concrete solution, we don't know given the little bit of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lazy solution: set names to `latin1` (or don't set it at all, as it's set by default).

It will return you results in original cp1251, which you can convert in any other encoding using iconv() or mb_convert_encoding().

Complex but proper solution: set the right encoding for the table columns. It have to be cp1251, not latin1. For this, you have to re-create tables using `CHARACTER SET=1251` in table definition and then re-filling tables back with data.

After that everything will be back in order:

- phpmyadmin will show your data  correctly
- you will be able to set names to `utf8` and get data in this encoding
- (most important part) `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` operators will stop driving you crazy.