# Converting UTF8 data to latin1 in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table with 70K+ data which is `utf8` encoded.

The data looks good on browser but on sql tools it looks like gibberish `à¤ªà¤µà¤` . Therefore I decided to convert this table data into `latin1` encoding and save it into another table.

But I am unable to write function to do it.  Please help. This problem has been haunting me for very long now.

**My Specs:**

```
PHP - 5.6.30
MYSQL - 5.7.22
```

Comment: I think you should read up on [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @Naruto I have read this question. I know UTF-8 is good for all purpose and I will continue to use it for operations in my application but I want the data in mysql table to be in readable format as well. That's why I want to convert it into a latin1

Comment: Can I suggest you configure your tools to work with UTF8 encoding or replace your tools with ones that do. What you are suggesting make no sense, and will generate you a lot of new Gibberish as UTF8 will not directly convert to latin1 without loosing lots of the utf8 data

Comment: Well you must do something wrong, because I have no problems at all with using UTF-8 all the way, and yes my data is readable in the database.

Comment: Which tools are causing you problems?

Comment: @Naruto can I show you some of my code. and you can help me from there.

Comment: You should look at the preferences of your "sql tool". You don't want to change the encoding of the table to make the text readable in different contexts.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am using php + mysql + phpmyadmin

Comment: What versions of these? All those (at current verions) should deal with UTF8 quite happily

Comment: php - 5.6.30 mysql -5.7.22

Comment: And phpMyAdmin? Is that a reasonably current version. I assume it is this you are mainly talking about when you say issues

Comment: @RiggsFolly I forgot to state that but I the data I am talking about is in hindi language not english.... maybe this is causing some issue.

Comment: @DeanAmbrose — Latin 1 isn't capable of expressing hindi characters! You need ISO-8859-12 for that … and that spec was never finished.

Comment: @Quentin I created a latin1 charset table and saved hindi data in it from google translate and it worked fine.

Comment: @Quentin can I express hindi characters with utf8?

Comment: If it's storing "à¤ªà¤µà¤", then it's *not* "working fine". See the duplicate.

Comment: @DeanAmbrose — MySQL charsets are *weird*. I suspect that while you might have labeled the table as being latin1, the data you were putting in it wasn't latin1.

Comment: @DeanAmbrose — UTF-8 supports *everything* (more or less, the lack of support for Klingon is a sore point in some circles).

Comment: @Quentin Meh… http://www.evertype.com/standards/csur/klingon.html

Comment: @Quentin so if my hindi data is saving as "à¤ªà¤µà¤" that means there is something wrong with my current settings??

Comment: because apart from their gibberish look in mysql the data looks good while performing other operations such as filtering comparision sorting etc.

Comment: Read [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Comment: @deceze thanks for the article... I guess what this article is trying to say is that converting to different encoding will lead to data loss and inefficiency in the back without the user knowing ....am I right?

Comment: It says that if you get the encoding settings wrong somewhere in the chain, then you're working with [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), which is never a good thing.

Comment: @deceze  In my case I have set the db table charset to be `UTF8` and encoding to `utf8_unicode_ci`. I have set `mysqli_set_charset($link, "UTF-8");` in my config file. My web form is accepting hindi data. So based on this can you suggest me something if I am doing anything wrong. **please this would be very very helpful for me.**

Comment: The encoding is called `utf8` in MySQL, or preferably even ***`utf8mb4`***.

Comment: you mean instead of `utf8_unicode_ci`?

Comment:  `mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8mb4')` 

Comment: okay so after using mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8mb4') my data is coming fine now....

but is there any way to recover my previous data.

Comment: Read. [The. Duplicate.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20237671/476)

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(field_name USING latin1) USING utf8) FROM table_name
 are you talking about this.

Comment: i think I got it.....since I was using wrong encoding 'UTF-8' instead of "utf8" my data got saved into latin1 format by defult. And now just need to convert it inti utf8 using the function in your answer.

Comment: thanks @deceze for your time and incredible help.