# PHP utf8_decode some characters decode correctly some not

Tags: php, utf-8

Okay, something went wrong in our database and now all the content from Chinese, Turkish etc. language is messed up (wrong characters). I'm trying to create a PHP script to convert it. Yes, `SET NAMES utf8` is executed, everything is `utf8mb4_general_ci` and the PDO connection has charset utf8.

For example, we got the following text:

```
Bizimle iletiÅŸime geÃ§in
```

Which is supposed to be:

```
Bizimle iletişime geçin
```

Now, if I display the output from the database, it displays the first line what we got in our database (`Bizimle iletiÅŸime geÃ§in`). Then, I use this line:

```
die(utf8_decode('Bizimle iletiÅŸime geÃ§in'));
```

The output of it is:

```
Bizimle ileti�?ime geçin
```

So the `Ã§` gets decoded correctly but the `ÅŸ` doesn't.

I tried going to an online utf8-decoder (https://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder) and if I try to decode `ÅŸ` it does show the `ş` correctly.

Comment: You are converting your string to Latin-1 encoding. This is an extremely limited encoding, which can not represent a whole lot of characters, especially Chinese and such.

Comment: So any way I can use PHP to fix those characters 100% correctly?

Comment: @Martin it doesn't help me further onto fixing the problem. I got headers set with charset utf8, meta tag with charset utf8, PDO connection is utf8mb4 now, set names is executed, tables and database is utf8mb4.

Comment: So apparently the data in the database is garbage…?!

Comment: Yes, that's why I was trying to use PHP to fix the data because I assumed that would work.

Comment: You’ve noticed this…? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20237671/476

Comment: Weird, I thought I saw something and it didn't work, nontheless, thanks.